# fixed positioned text while container div moved

Tags: html, css

When my function is called to make sidebar width change from 0px to 418px, I'd like the text inside the list to stay fixed. However, if I simply use position:fixed, it would show the text before the sidebar is shown. Is there anyway to make the text stay aligned while its parent div changes size?

```
#sidebar ul li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c6d0da;
    height:57px;
    padding:10px 0px;
}
```

Javascript function to increase sidebar size:

```
function menu() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "418px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.marginLeft = "450px";
}
```

Comment: Did you try overflow: hidden on your container ?
If you want people helps you please provide a full example (HTML / CSS / JS). You can make a snippet example with Stack Overflow, or use something like Plunker

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/2gEVN4jqDmnr3y3FdFw3?p=preview

Comment: I don't understand your issue, I can't see the text until the sidebar is big enough to display it

Comment: when the menu icon is hovered, the sidebar increases size by about 75px so the icons can only be shown, then when the user hovers over the sidebar it increases to 418px, my problem is that the text shows underneath the logo, I'd like it so they can only see the text after sidebar is hovered.

Sorry, I can see how my original explanation was confusing for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated you code, but it brokes a little the css inside the sidebar.
I changed you  innerHtml by regrouping picture and a with a div, and i used a div instead of your a element.

Please, don't use Ids like that, an Id should be unique. Use class instead. If you want to write a better javaScript code, use JQuery too. It's very, very easier to use than native javascript.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VnSu7R8MiuiPaB0afERc?p=preview)

```
#icon-li > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#icon-li > div > * {
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.